# Keyboard hides when using useState in TextInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a text input inside the tab view in which I have used setState for updating the value of the input.

```
export function Login(){

  const [email, setEmail] = useState();

  return(
  <View>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={setEmail}
        value={email}
      />
   </View>
  )
}
```

Now every time I called setEmail on onChangeText input gets hides. Is there anything using which I can prevent the keyboard from getting close?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/red-pine-8k70f?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Is this your exact code? Cause this example should work

Comment: Share more logic from your component that you are using to better helping you.
What is TextInput?

Comment: I agree share more of the code. Your current example @JhonataBonadio works

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the synthetic event listener and set the state to the desired value:

import React from "react";

```
export default function App() {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <>
      <input onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} value={email} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried to do and this warning appeared: The property 'value' does not exist in the type 'number'.

Comment: I dont know the exact components you are using. what exactly is <TextInput> ?

Comment: Fixed this by removing the "TouchableWithoutFeedback" from my code.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you define a nested component as in the code below:

```
const ListMenu = () => {
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");
    const Header = () => {
        return <TextInput
           placeholder="Search"
           onChangeText={text => { setSearchText(text) }}
         />
    }
    return (<View>
               <Header />
           </View>
    )}
```

instead make nested component like this:

```
    const ListMenu = () => {
        const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");
        const header = () => {
           return <TextInput
                    placeholder="Search"
                    onChangeText={text => { setSearchText(text) }} />
    }
    return (<View> {header()} </View>)
}
```